# Drawn myself into a box with Google Ads API. Can't authenticate other users besides mine

Tags: google-ads-api, awql

I'm working on building a new tool for my customers that helps automate their ads and see daily / weekly reports and improvements.  However, I'm having a humbling issue with the Google Ads API.  I've set up a manager account, and my clients have given me access.  However, it won't let me see their clicks.  Google has ever so delicately told me that my manager account will not let me see their clicks within the API.  I can see them in my dashboard.  But I can't call them with my API.  Am I not supposed to build a good report for my customers?  Any query through manual requests on AWQL results the same.  I don't know why I can't get their clicks/performance.  Google's told me, "It's not me.  It's you."

I have my Google Dev token.  My own Oauth2 on my manager account.  I thought the purpose of the manager account was so I could have the API.  Have been reading for hours, but I'm missing something simple.  What should I be requesting / authenticating with to get the clicks for my clients?

Signed,  noob old developer working for 24 hours straight.

Answer (score 0):

Want to update as I finally got an update from G Ads Support.  It's authenticating successfully but it doesn't have the data in AWQL.  The Google Ads manager account can't query clicks and analytics.

You need to authenticate the client account into OAuth2.  After authentication, then you can view clicks, visitors, impressions.  That kinda stops my email reports, but I can workaround by a link that populates that data for my customers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's true. If you have manager account access, you should be able to access everything you can see in the web UI through the API. You're right, that is one of the points in having MCC/Manager account access.

How are you authorizing? Are you using the client libraries? What's getting returned when you make a call?